# Get all json key and value from an external json file in MVC with javascript

Tags: javascript, json, model-view-controller

I am creating a web app in which I have a `Json` file in which I have many keys with values, like the following,

```
{
  "Login_Header_Text": "Login",
  "Login_Header_Recent_Updates": "Recent Updates",
  "Login_TextBox_UserName": "User Name",
  "Login_TextBox_Password": "Password",
  "Login_Button_Login": "Log In",
  "Login_ErrorMessage_Usernamerequired": "User name required",
  "Login_ErrorMessage_Passwordrequired": "Password required.",
  "Login_ErrorMessage_Invalid_Credentials": "Invalid user name/password",
}
```

and I can retrieve the values like the following

```
<script>
       console.log('@HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("", "Login_TextBox_UserName")');
</script>
```

now, how can I retrieve whole json file data and print that into my `console`,

Like, if I have 55 Records in the json file, whole data should be printed in `console.log`

what is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Is this javascript related or are you trying to parse the json file on the server side, like your line of code suggests?

Comment: console.log(JSON.stringify(data))?

Comment: @James updated my Question

Comment: It appears to be server-side code only.  You're not trying to get that JSON into the browser by AJAX or anything.

Answer (score 0):

here is how i would do it. in C# and also in javascript

assum we have this js

```
var json = [{Name: "test", Passowrd:"test" }]
```

in C# i would convert this to class

```
public class myjson{

public string Name { get; set;}

public string Password { get; set;}
}
```

then with reflection call on the property

```
public GetValue(this myjson o, string propertyName){
return o.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(o);
}
```

in Jsvascript i would just call this

```
var value = json[0][property]
```

I hop this could help you

Answer (score 0):

hello I think this can help you, I made a small example by picking up an answer written in Ajax and writing it in the console.

Look at the function in success, I think that's what you're looking for

```
function formToJSON(form) {
    var obj = {};
    var elements = form.querySelectorAll("input, select, textarea");
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
        var element = elements[i];
        var name = element.name;
        var value = element.value;

        if (name) {
            obj[name] = value;
        }
    }

    return obj;
}

function test(id, url, method) {
        var data = formToJSON(document.getElementById(id));
        $.ajax({
            type: method,
            url: url,
            data: data,
            success: function (output, status, xhr) {
                var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);//<--- here is your JSON
                for (var item in response) { // and set for to  print indivual 
                    console.log(item+' '+response[item]);
                }
                console.log(response);
            },
            cache: false
        });
    }
```